# What is the best way to escape non-format characters in Oracle's to_char?

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

I am trying to print a date in a select statement, but I need to add a letter to the output:

```
to_char(date_updated, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')
```

Oracle does not like the T. I just want the T to be output like the colons and the dashes. Can I escape it with a backslash or something?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You just need double-quotes around it:

```
to_char(date_updated, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: Thanks for this - once again Stack Overflow has saved my bacon.

Comment: What to do if I want to escape a double quote(") ?

Comment: Maybe `'YYYY-MM-DD"""T"""HH:mm:ss'` - not tested

Comment: Escape `"` with `\"`. Example `'YYYY-MM-DD\"HH:mm:ss\"'` → 2022-12-23 "12:46:06"