# converting sysdate to datetime format

Tags: oracle, sysdate

I have sysdate:

```
    04-JUN-14
```

and I need to convert it to datetime:

```
    i.e.:   2014-06-04T01:00:02
    format: yyyy-mm-ddThh24:mi:ss
```

is this doable?

Comment: Yes, did you look at the to_char and to_date functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little trick because of the `T` inside your format, so you have to cut it in two:

```
with w as
(
  select sysdate d from dual
)
select to_char(w.d, 'yyyy-mm-dd') || 'T' || to_char(w.d, 'hh24:mi:ss')
from w;
```

**EDIT :** A better way exists in a single call to `to_char`, as shown in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588430/what-is-the-best-way-to-escape-non-format-characters-in-oracles-to-char):

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```